# How can I format chart.js data labels while using chart.js datalabels plugin?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this chart working in chart.js and it pulls the data in from a csv file. I'm happy with where I've gotten so far but I still can't seem to affect the styling in certain ways. I am using chart.js old version 2.9.3

1. I am using the datalabel plugin to add the values to the bars on the chart but how do I style the font for the values? I want to colour them and make them display outside the area of the bars. I keep trying to put the style tags in different areas but nothing seems to work. I am using red for testing purposes in my code.
   I also tried a javascript function called formatter but that doesn't seem to do anything either. Maybe I have my variable names wrong?
2. I also want to get rid of the numbers along the bottom but tick: {display: false} does not seem to work.

Sorry I am such a newbie at code and feel so frustrated. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Project 1</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/1.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-XulchVN83YTvsOaBGjLeApZuasKd8F4ZZ28/aMHevKjzrrjG0lor+T4VU248fWYMNki3Eimk+uwdlQS+uZmu8g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>MY CHART HERE</h1>
    <h2>Results of a survey </h2>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="250" style="background-color:white;"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', setup);

    async function setup() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var poll = await getData();
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',

        data: {
          labels: poll.years,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'how many people (%)',
            data: poll.vals,


            backgroundColor: [
              '#cd0000',
              '#eb7d44',
              '#70AA5B',
              '#CAF0FD',
              '#134D85',
            ],
          }]
        },

        options: {
          scaleShowLabels: false,
          plugins: {
            datalabels: {
              align: 'end',
              color: 'red',
              formatter: function(value, context) {
                return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
              }

            }
          },

          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 8,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },

          responsive: true,
          title: {
            display: false
          },


          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            usePointStyle: true,
            padding: 1,
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 15
            }
          },

          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                display: false,
                color: '#ffffff',
                zeroLineColor: '#ffffff'
              }
            }],

            xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                display: false
              },
            }],
          }
        },

        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        options: {
          datalabels: {
            color: 'red',
            align: 'end'
          }
        },

      });
    }

    async function getData() {
      // const response = await fetch('testdata.csv');
      var response = await fetch('data/test2.csv');
      var data = await response.text();
      data = data.replace(/"/g, "");
      var years = [];
      var vals = [];
      var rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);

      rows = rows.slice(0, rows.length - 1);
      rows = rows.filter(row => row.length !== 0)

      rows.forEach(row => {
        var cols = row.split(",");
        years.push(cols[0]);
        vals.push(0 + parseFloat(cols[2]));
      });
      console.log(years, vals);
      return {
        years,
        vals
      };

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Image of chart:

[image: Image of chart]

Comment: I also can't seem to post a picture here. Ugg!!

Comment: Here is a link to a screen grab of the chart
https://www.dropbox.com/s/42absds48cpsj3p/chart.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide a working sample of your problem but with what you provided it works fine, color of the labels for the datalabels plugin has changed and the y ticks are hidden: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/xfn84bmo/13/

Comment: Hi Leelen. I don't think I can provide a link to the server location as it is through my employer. Can you see in the screen grab that I posted above how the bottom scale is still showing on there? Also I see you declared options as a variable. Do I need to do this to make the data values show up as red? ugg. I feel totally lost.

Comment: In this function should it be poll.vals or maybe data instead of labels for the numbers on my bars?

        ```      formatter: function (value, context) {
                return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
              }```

Comment: The formatter function is only used if you want to change the displayed text by including a dollar sign for example, since you are not doing that you can just remove the formatter function

Comment: oh ok, well that helps.

Comment: ah I will see if I can sign up and get a working sample on the jsfiddle. I am very slow so could take me some time.

Comment: found the real issue, see answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your issue, you are defining the `options` block a second time after your `plugins` section, this overrides the earlyer options block as there are no duplicate keys allowed in js objects, so if you change your config to this it will work:

```js
async function setup() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var poll = await getData();
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: poll.years,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'how many people (%)',
                data: poll.vals,
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#cd0000',
                    '#eb7d44',
                    '#70AA5B',
                    '#CAF0FD',
                    '#134D85',
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scaleShowLabels: false,
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    align: 'end',
                    color: 'red',
                }
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: 8,
                    bottom: 0
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: false
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                usePointStyle: true,
                padding: 1,
                labels: {
                    boxWidth: 15
                }
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: false,
                        fontColor: '#ffffff',
                        zeroLineColor: '#ffffff'
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: false
                    },
                }],
            }
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    });
}
```

Comment: You are a miracle. One simple thing and all of those things wouldn't work. Now I know to not use any of these twice and also about that function and what it was doing. I really really appreciate this. 

Comment: wondering if I could ask you one more question. Do you know where I would style the names for the bars on the yaxis? Does it go in the scales section? I am having such trouble with this stuff.
   scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                  color: 'red'
                }

Comment: You need to use the property `fontColor` instead of `color`

Comment: I found it. Thanks!